# Color scale legend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer, legend

I have been trying for hours to add a color scale to my vector layer in order to avoid showing all those boxes in my legend.

But I don't find any solution. I tried the Geoproc plugin without success, it only works with rasters and my layer is a vector. I also tried generating .qml files but the Geoproc plugin did not accept them.

Does anyone have an idea?

[image: example1]

I would like a color scale like this but in red:

[image: example2]

Comment: Hi @Taras, yes I went for the rectangle option and this is quite ok. I thought there was something a little bit more "automated" Thanks a lot !

Comment: IMHO less effortless but still efficient workflow can be done by means of a graphical editor. Where you export the result and import it into QGIS as an icon.

Comment: Ok, I will go for the graphical editor. Thanks a lot @Taras !

Comment: My pleasure and always welcome

Comment: @Taras do I need to tick a box in order to select the post where u replied to my question? Like this small triangle on the left for example

Comment: I can suggest [making a tour on GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).